# How to use i18n feature in CQ5 for different languages at page level not at user level?

Tags: internationalization, aem

I need to use **i18n** in my component at **page level**, i have implemented it by creating **i18n folder for french language** but i am not getting the exact result. When i change the user language to french then i get the desired output, so my question is that i18n implementation is only for **user language level** or is there any customization which needs to be done so as to have the desired output at **page level**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the java `com.day.I18n` API, you need to initialize it with a resource bundle based on the page's language:

```
I18n i18n = new I18n(slingRequest.getResourceBundle(currentPage.getLanguage(false)));
```